# Scrapy Selector issue

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class PriceSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'price'
    start_urls = ['https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:A']

    def parse(self,response):
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="d-dquote-x3"]//text()').extract()
        print(price)
```

I am trying to extract the price from this line of html:

```
<div><span class="d-dquote-x3">72.99</span>
```

it returns an empty list, how can I make it so the price(72.99) is my output?

EDIT: I believe it is an issue regarding the website having dynamic content, can anyone confirm this and if so suggest a course of action?

Comment: Try this to get the data `response.css('.d-dquote-x3::text').extract_first()`. However, you will only locate the data once you use `splash` or any browser simulator like `selenium` in combination with `scrapy` to render the dynamically generated content.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is wrong selector. Your element is

```
<div><span class="d-dquote-x3">72.99</span>
```

So the class is associated with the `span` and not the `div`. You need

```
price = response.xpath('//span[@class="d-dquote-x3"]//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that page has dynamic content. It's pretty obvious from the way it loads in the browser, but you can also check by getting the html more directly and looking at it. I do this like so:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:A')
with open('/tmp/test.html', 'w') as out:
    out.write(response.text)
```

And then I look at /tmp/test.html in the browser. There is no quote data.

If you want to get this data you're going to need to look into [headless browsers](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).